# Compare a list of strings with each other in R

Tags: r, nlp, levenshtein-distance

I am trying to compare a list of strings with each other using the function levenshteinSim() from package 'RecordLinkage'. However, I am having a very hard time to figure out how I can incorporate my list of strings into the function as it only takes two arguments str1 and str2. I am trying to find the most optimal way as my list contains 4k strings. Any help is much appreciated!

Below is some sample data:

```
sample <- c('apple', 'appeal', 'apparel', 'peel', 'peer', 'pear')
```

Comment: wanna mark one of the responses as the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I think this might be what you want. The `RecordLinkage` package is not on CRAN anymore, so I went for another package that calculates the Levenshtein distance:

```
library(stringdist)

sample <- c('apple', 'appeal', 'apparel', 'peel', 'peer', 'pear')

df <- expand.grid(sample, sample) # this creates a dataframe of all combinations of the sample elements

stringdist(df$Var1, df$Var2, method = "lv")
```

Output:

```
[1] 0 3 3 4 4 4 3 0 3 3 4 3 3 3 0 4 5 4 4 3 4 0 1 2 4 4 5 1 0 1 4 3 4 2 1 0
```

And maybe a little more appealing - the `dplyr` version:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
    mutate(levenshtein = stringdist(Var1, Var2, method = "lv"))
```

which outputs

```
     Var1  Var2 levenshtein
1   apple apple           0
2  appeal apple           3
3 apparel apple           3
4    peel apple           4
5    peer apple           4
6    pear apple           4
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R solution to obtain the distance matrix

```
z <- Map(utf8ToInt,sample)
dmat <- outer(z,z,FUN = Vectorize(function(x,y) sum(bitwXor(x,y)>0)))
```

such that

```
> dmat
        apple appeal apparel peel peer pear
apple       0      3       4    4    5    5
appeal      3      0       4    6    6    6
apparel     4      4       0    6    6    6
peel        4      6       6    0    1    2
peer        5      6       6    1    0    1
pear        5      6       6    2    1    0
```

Answer (score 1):

Getting the levenshtein distance or levenshtein similarity is pretty straightforward without the `RecordLinkage` package, which was recently removed from CRAN.

In base R:

```
sample <- c('apple', 'appeal', 'apparel', 'peel', 'peer', 'pear')
adist(sample)
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
#> [1,]    0    3    3    4    4    4
#> [2,]    3    0    3    3    4    3
#> [3,]    3    3    0    4    5    4
#> [4,]    4    3    4    0    1    2
#> [5,]    4    4    5    1    0    1
#> [6,]    4    3    4    2    1    0
```

Using the much faster `stringdist` package (which supports a bunch of alternative methods to levenshtein distance, check `help("stringdist-metrics")`)

```
stringdist::stringdistmatrix(sample, method = "lv", useNames = "strings")
#>         apple appeal apparel peel peer
#> appeal      3                         
#> apparel     3      3                  
#> peel        4      3       4          
#> peer        4      4       5    1     
#> pear        4      3       4    2    1
```

If you want string similarly instead, you can use `stringsim()` or `stringsimmatrix` to get all comparisons at once (only available in the development version so far; `devtools::install_github("markvanderloo/stringdist/pkg")`):

```
stringdist::stringsimmatrix(sample, method = "lv", useNames = "strings")
#>             apple    appeal apparel      peel      peer      pear
#> apple   1.0000000 0.4000000     0.4 0.2000000 0.2000000 0.2000000
#> appeal  0.5000000 1.0000000     0.5 0.5000000 0.3333333 0.5000000
#> apparel 0.5714286 0.5714286     1.0 0.4285714 0.2857143 0.4285714
#> peel    0.0000000 0.2500000     0.0 1.0000000 0.7500000 0.5000000
#> peer    0.0000000 0.0000000     0.0 0.7500000 1.0000000 0.7500000
#> pear    0.0000000 0.2500000     0.0 0.5000000 0.7500000 1.0000000
```

If you want to get this into a tidy format, you could do the following:

```
library(tidyverse)
stringdist::stringsimmatrix(sample, method = "lv", useNames = "strings") %>% 
  as.matrix() %>%
  as_tibble(rownames = "word1") %>% 
  pivot_longer(-word1, names_to = "word2", values_to = "distance")
#> # A tibble: 36 x 3
#>    word1  word2   distance
#>    <chr>  <chr>      <dbl>
#>  1 apple  apple      1    
#>  2 apple  appeal     0.4  
#>  3 apple  apparel    0.4  
#>  4 apple  peel       0.200
#>  5 apple  peer       0.200
#>  6 apple  pear       0.200
#>  7 appeal apple      0.5  
#>  8 appeal appeal     1    
#>  9 appeal apparel    0.5  
#> 10 appeal peel       0.5  
#> # ... with 26 more rows
```

Comment: Nice to see `adist`, liked it!